# how to force new session cookie / sessionId when switching from http to https (in Tomcat)

Tags: http, tomcat, https, seam, session-cookies

my question upfront is:

When changing from http to https: How do I enforce on Tomcat that the value of the JSESSIONID / (i.e. the session cookie) gets changed?

Here's my situation:

I assume we are having a potential security issue in our application and wonder how to fix it.

We run a JSF1.2 / Seam2 application inside of a Tomcat 6.x and force the usage of session cookies (no sessionid in URLs).

We allow http access, but when a user logs in we switch to https and stay on https.
We also do have a Filter that adds 'secure' to the cookie whenever the request is coming through https to ensure that the session cannot go back to http.
(somehow I thought Tomcat would do that automatically)

I noticed that the JSESSIONID doesn't change when switching between http and https.
This suggests to me that an attacker could potentially spy out the session cookie through http and then hijack the session.

So how can I tell Tomcat to use a different JSESSIONID when changing to https? 
(Or if thats the default behavior: What could lead to this not happening anymore?)

Thanks for any hints/ideas!

Comment: How are you testing the change of JSESSIONID? I've tested on v6.0.20 and enabled the Tomcat RequestDumperValve - it shows me a change of JSESSIONID from http into https

Comment: Hi, I am just simply looking at the JSESSIONID in my browser (request/response headers). There it never changes.. I'll try to enable the RequestDumperValve (I hadn't heard of that) and will check again..

Comment: yeah, for me it doesn't do a change of JSESSIONID :( .. now I need to find out why this doesn't happen I guess :(

Comment: can you try a new dummy web app with just 1 secure page and one non-secure? That way we can know if it is a problem within tomcat or something about the JSF/Seam application

Comment: Why would you allow exchange of login credentials for a cookie over HTTP in the first place? You are overcomplicating the solution, and it won't even work

Answer (score 1):

some time (years actually) I posted this filter here that we use to renew the session ID after the login:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBSEAM-2450

We call newSession() just after a login to mark the session-ID to be renewed on the next GET request (POST requests don't work well due to the restore of the view state, but the POST/REDIRECT/GET with Seam will issue GETs quite often).

You might want put it into your filter -- or you just mark your session to be refreshed in the next GET request. Just make sure that you don't renew your session when processing a JSF POST request.

Someone else also provided a Tomcat Valve to solve this

Best regards,
Alexander.